# WPF program fails to start when installed in target machine (CefSharp related)

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp in my WPF application. Executing it from the Debug folder, and copying the entire folder to target machine works flawlessly.

I made a setup project and selected to copy Primary output, but after installing the app crashes upon start.

After copying individual files from debug to installation folder I discovered that these files are the one missing which make the app crash:

- cef.pak
- cef_100_percent.pak
- cef_200_percent.pak
- cef_extensions.pak

I guess these are related to CefSharp but I don't understand why they aren't installed.

Which is the proper way to fix this issue?

Comment: In your setup project you can add them as files to the "Application Folder". When the msi file is generated they will be packaged and during the install copied to the installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

Found the list of requirement for CefSharp in Setup Project, I just need to add them manually.

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-(Redistribution)